# Marking all groups in DataFrame smaller than N

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to mark (in `ok`) all groups in a pandas DataFrame which are smaller than 'N'. I have a working solution but it's slow, is there a way to speed this up?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 2],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 1],
    [2, 3, 2],
    [4, 5, 1],
    [4, 5, 2],
    [4, 5, 3],
], columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])


keys = ['x', 'y']
N = 3

df['ok'] = True
c = df.groupby(keys)['ok'].count()
for vals in c[c < N].index:
    local_dict = dict(zip(keys, vals))
    query = ' & '.join(f'{key}==@{key}' for key in keys)
    idx = df.query(query, local_dict=local_dict).index
    df.loc[idx, 'ok'] = False
print(df)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `groupby/count`, use [`groupby/transform/count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) to form a Series *which is the same length* as the original DataFrame `df`:

```
c = df.groupby(keys)['z'].transform('count')
```

Then you can form a boolean mask which has the same length as `df`:

```
In [35]: c<N
Out[35]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
Name: ok, dtype: bool
```

Assignment to `ok` goes much more smoothly now, without a loop, querying or sub-indexing:

```
df['ok'] = c >= N
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 2],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 1],
    [2, 3, 2],
    [4, 5, 1],
    [4, 5, 2],
    [4, 5, 3],
], columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])


keys = ['x', 'y']
N = 3

c = df.groupby(keys)['z'].transform('count')
df['ok'] = c >= N
print(df)
```

yields

```
   x  y  z     ok
0  1  2  1   True
1  1  2  2   True
2  1  2  3   True
3  2  3  1  False
4  2  3  2  False
5  4  5  1   True
6  4  5  2   True
7  4  5  3   True
```

---

Since the [builtin `groupby/transform` methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#id32) (such as `transform('count')`) are
Cythonized they are in general faster than calling `groupby/transform`
with an custom lambda function. 
Thus, computing the `ok` column in two steps using

```
c = df.groupby(keys)['z'].transform('count')
df['ok'] = c >= N
```

is faster than

```
df.assign(ok=df.groupby(keys)['z'].transform(lambda x: x.size >= N))
```

In addition, vectorized operations over an entire column (such as `c >= N`), are
faster than multiple operations over subgroups. `transform(lambda x: x.size >=
N))` performs the comparison `x.size >= N` once for each group. If there are
many groups, then computing `c >= N` yields an improvement in performance.

---

For example, with this 1000-row DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2017)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(1000, 3)), columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
keys = ['x', 'y']
N = 3
```

using `transform('count')` is about 12x faster:

```
In [37]: %%timeit
   ....: c = df.groupby(keys)['z'].transform('count')
   ....: df['ok'] = c >= N
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.69 ms per loop

In [38]: %timeit df.assign(ok=df.groupby(keys)['z'].transform(lambda x: x.size >= N))
1 loop, best of 3: 20.2 ms per loop

In [39]: 20.2/1.69
Out[39]: 11.95266272189349
```

In the example above there were 100 groups:

```
In [47]: df.groupby(keys).ngroups   
Out[47]: 100
```

The speed advantage of using `transform('count')` increases as the number of
groups increase. For example, with 955 groups:

```
In [48]: np.random.seed(2017); df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(1000, 3)), columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])

In [51]: df.groupby(keys).ngroups
Out[51]: 955
```

the `transform('count')` method performs about 92x faster:

```
In [49]: %%timeit
   ....: c = df.groupby(keys)['z'].transform('count')
   ....: df['ok'] = c >= N
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.88 ms per loop

In [50]: %timeit df.assign(ok=df.groupby(keys)['z'].transform(lambda x: x.size >= N))
10 loops, best of 3: 173 ms per loop

In [52]: 173/1.88
Out[52]: 92.02127659574468
```

Answer (score 1):

Input variables:

```
keys = ['x','y']
N = 3
```

Calculate okay or not with `groupby`, `transform` and `size`:

```
df.assign(ok=df.groupby(keys)['z'].transform(lambda x: x.size >= N))
```

Output:

```
   x  y  z     ok
0  1  2  1   True
1  1  2  2   True
2  1  2  3   True
3  2  3  1  False
4  2  3  2  False
5  4  5  1   True
6  4  5  2   True
7  4  5  3   True
```